# Sending Email using jquery ajax,webservice and c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I don't know what I am doing wrong. My code keeps giving me this error.

> jquery.js:10254 POST http://localhost:7855/Services/svUsers.asmx/EmailNotification 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my all my code

```
[WebMethod]
public bool EmailNotification(string from,string to,string username)
{
    MailMessage tmail = new MailMessage();
    tmail.From = new MailAddress(from);
    tmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(string.Format("Dear {0} <br/><br/>",username));
    builder.Append("How are you john iliya i am testing Sending Email Messages with Webservice...i have faith it would work...");
    builder.Append(("<br/><br/>"));
    builder.Append("<b>Powered By JINGBREEDS.com");
    tmail.Subject = "Testing Of Mail Messages";
    tmail.Body = builder.ToString();
    tmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    tmail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourun@gmail.com","yourpswd");
    }
    smtp.Send(tmail);
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="txtEMF"  class="form-control" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="txtEMT"  class="form-control" />
<input type="button" class="btn-info btn form-control" name="btnSend" value="Send"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='btnSend']").click(function () {
            var un = "airmarshalg";
            $.ajax({
                url: "../Services/svUsers.asmx/EmailNotification",
                method: "POST",
                data: { from: $("input[name$='txtEMF']").val(), to: $("input[name$='txtEMT']").val(), username: un },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.data == true)
                    {
                        alert("Hurray message sent...");
                    }                               
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To expand on Will's comment, you need to figure out what the underlying reason is that the server returned an HTTP 500. This might mean adding logging, or stepping through the code with the debugger attached.

Comment: Did you debug the code to figure out what is going wrong there?

Comment: i am a newbie to programming sir ...i do not know how step into the code with a debugger attached

Comment: Start by putting a break point the first line of the EmailNotification method and see if it's hit. Then use F10 to step through the method to see where it gets.

Comment: when i run the webservice alone it works and it sends the mail to My mail address but when i try to run it with ajax call it throws an error

Comment: When you run it through the AJAX call is the break point on the server i suggested being hit?

Comment: yes sir and it showed this

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the problem by uncommenting this line of code in the very top of my webservice..what a terrible error from me
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Thanks guys code works like charm hahahah using it with angular